# Not able to update the pod images of a ReplicationController in K8S

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I created a ReplicationController using the below command.

> kubectl run nginx --image=nginx -r=2 --generator=run/v1

Now I tried upgrading the image to version 1.7.1.

> kubectl set image rc/nginx nginx=nginx:1.7.1

But, the image doesn't seem to update.

> watch -n1 "kubectl describe pods | grep "Image:""

Also tried `kubectl edit ....` and the `kubectl apply -f ....` command, but the image is not getting updated.

How do I update an image in K8S ReplicationController?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here in documentation is described how to make rolling upgrade on replication controllers https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/replicationcontroller/#rolling-updates

You need to know that actually your image is updated in replication controller but replication controller won't kill existing pods and spawn new with new image. So to achieve that you need to do one of 2 options:

1. Manually kill pods
2. Scale your RC to 0 to kill pods and then to desired number of replicas using following command `kubectl scale --replicas=3 rc/nginx`

Answer (score 1):

Replication controller is only able to scale numbers of replicas of given pod and can't do any updates.

There is a way to "update" your ReplicationController using `kubectl rolling-update`, but it does not update it literally. 
That what is happening when you run `kubectl rolling-update` ([link1](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/rolling-update-replication-controller/)):

> 1. Creating a new replication controller with the updated configuration.
> 2. Increasing/decreasing the replica count on the new and old controllers until the correct number of replicas is reached.
> 3. Deleting the original replication controller.
>
> Rolling updates are initiated with the kubectl rolling-update command:
>
> ```
> $ kubectl rolling-update NAME \
>     ([NEW_NAME] --image=IMAGE | -f FILE)
> ```

Assume that we have a current replication controller named foo and it is running image image:v1  ([link2](https://github.com/kubernetes/community/blob/master/contributors/design-proposals/cli/simple-rolling-update.md))

```
kubectl rolling-update foo [foo-v2] --image=myimage:v2
```

> If the user doesn't specify a name for the 'next' replication
>   controller, then the 'next' replication controller is renamed to the
>   name of the original replication controller.

Here are some more examples from the [kubectl reference](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands#rolling-update):

> Update pods of frontend-v1 using new replication controller data in
>   frontend-v2.json.
>
> ```
> kubectl rolling-update frontend-v1 -f frontend-v2.json
> ```
>
> Update pods of frontend-v1 using JSON data passed into stdin.
>
> ```
> cat frontend-v2.json | kubectl rolling-update frontend-v1 -f -
> ```
>
> Update the pods of frontend-v1 to frontend-v2 by just changing the
>   image, and switching the # name of the replication controller.
>
> ```
> kubectl rolling-update frontend-v1 frontend-v2 --image=image:v2
> ```
>
> Update the pods of frontend by just changing the image, and keeping
>   the old name.
>
> ```
> kubectl rolling-update frontend --image=image:v2
> ```
>
> Abort and reverse an existing rollout in progress (from frontend-v1 to
>   frontend-v2).
>
> ```
> kubectl rolling-update frontend-v1 frontend-v2 --rollback
> ```

There are **alternatives** to the ReplicationController ([link3](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/replicationcontroller/#alternatives-to-replicationcontroller))

[**ReplicaSet**](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/replicaset/) (Still it does not support updating Pod's image)

> ReplicaSet is the next-generation ReplicationController that supports
>   the new set-based label selector. It’s mainly used by Deployment as a
>   mechanism to orchestrate pod creation, deletion and updates. Note that
>   we recommend using Deployments instead of directly using Replica Sets,
>   unless you require custom update orchestration or don’t require
>   updates at all.

[**Deployment**](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/) (Recommended) (It works as an orchestrator for ReplicaSets, so it supports updates by design)

> Deployment is a higher-level API object that updates its underlying
>   Replica Sets and their Pods in a similar fashion as `kubectl rolling-update`.
>   Deployments are recommended if you want this rolling
>   update functionality, because unlike `kubectl rolling-update`, they are
>   declarative, server-side, and have additional features.

```
kubectl run nginx1 --image nginx --replicas=3
kubectl get deployment nginx1 --export -o yaml
```